# Android O background limitations

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

It's not clear from docs if the app can call `startService()` if it's in idle state after receiving an intent. The docs talks about sms/MMS broadcast intent, it's not clear if the app is placed in whitelist if it receives *any* intent via broadcast receiver. Until now I didn't find a way to test it putting the app in idle state. Any tips?

Comment: If you need to run Services always, use Application class to initiate your service. No need to worry about app state and other states of application

Comment: What???? Application class? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: `startService` can be called as many times as you need it, however if you want to do that 100s of times it is much better to use "bound service" pattern

Comment: You can't bound a service from a brodcast receiver. In addition startService throws IlllegalStateException now if the app is in idle state.

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver#peekService(Context myContext, Intent service)`

Comment: My service is an intent service, peekService won't work at all

Comment: so either make it regular `Service` or use `startService` for submitting each request

Comment: I don't want to use an always-on foreground service, it's really poor design on android

Comment: what stops you from using `Context#stopService` / `Service#stopSelf` ?

Comment: If I have an already running service and I call stopSelf, I return exactly to the same point. I need to start the service from my broadcast receiver.

Comment: I think you really need to read Android o docs before to comment

Comment: indeed i just realized we are talking about the "android **O** preview" - basically i dont pay special attention on question `tags` and the title "Android o background limitations" seemed to me like "Android's background limitations"...

Comment: I put the app in idle state by pressing Home button and then opening some other apps. After a minute or so my app is in _idle_ state. I confirmed it as app no longer can start a Service in that state.

Comment: Also, similar situation with a service behaving like white-listed from some other kind of Intent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889604/android-o-background-service-is-running-for-more-than-30-minutes-why

Comment: yep, but the behavior seems related to the "ignore battery optimization". If the app is in whitelist the limitations are not applied

Comment: @greywolf82 but my app is 'battery optimized' and the background Service still keeps running for extended periods of time. How one can know if app is in whitelist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I reply to myself: no, only some system intents put the app in whitelist

Answer (score 0):

Since Android O you can only call startService() if:

1. Your app is in the foreground.
2. You use a JobScheduler/JobService to wrap the call.

For #2 you basically replace:

```
startService(startMyServiceIntent);
```

With this:

```
ComponentName serviceName          = new ComponentName(context, MyJobService.class);
JobScheduler  jobScheduler          = (JobScheduler)context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHDULER_SERVICE);
JobInfo       startMySerivceJobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(MyJobService.JOB_ID, serviceName).setMinimumLatency(100).build();
int           result                = jobScheduler.schedule(startMyServiceJobInfo);
```

Then you just need a class that extends JobService to actually start the service:

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {
  public static final int JOB_ID = 0;  // app unique job id. 

  @Override
  public boolean onJobStart(JobParameters params) {
    ...
    startService(startMyServiceIntent);
    ...
    return false;
  }
}
```

This will start your service in the foreground or the background. There are still background limits on how long a back ground service can run. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44241192/786462