# JobScheduler behaviour on Android O

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

[According to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#services), as of Android O services will be stopped several minutes after the app is no longer in the foreground.

The documentation suggests most services can be replaced with JobScheduler jobs. My question is - do jobs have any kind of special behavior as well, or do they behave the same as services pre-Android O? Can they live "forever" (as long as the system doesn't need the memory, of course), or do the system also kills them off at the end of a certain window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can they live "forever" (as long as the system doesn't need the memory, of course), or do the system also kills them off at the end of a certain window?

No. In my testing, you have ~10 minutes, as opposed to the ~1 minute for a regular service.

If you need a service that runs forever, you will need to make it be a foreground service (`startForegroundService()` on Android O+, or `startService()` plus `startForeground()` on Android 7.1 and earlier).

Comment: What's the state of my app during those 10 minutes? As I understand it there are 3 states - Foreground, then the 1 minute "window", then idle. If I schedule a job to start after the app is idle, is the app's state the same as the "window"?

Comment: I've noticed that you can also start a background service using a JobScheduler and not get an IllegalStateException, which is nice.

Comment: @DataDino: That's interesting. I guess that being bound to by the core OS while the job is outstanding is sufficient to let you start services. It fits the docs, but I had not considered it. Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare, It's in the official docs: "In most cases, apps can work around these limitations by using JobScheduler jobs"  here: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html :)

Comment: @DataDino: My interpretation of that, though, is doing the work *in the jobs*, not kicking off a service from the jobs. IOW, the `JobService` is where the work gets done, not in some secondary service that the `JobService` starts.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Can you clarify why did you say it fits the docs? I also read it the same way you did and DataDino's finding looked like a bug to me

Comment: @OriWasserman: Well, [the docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#services) say that an app is considered to be foreground if "Another foreground app is connected to the app, either by binding to one of its services or by making use of one of its content providers". A `JobService` is a bound service. So, my guess is that while a job is started, the `JobService` is bound to in a way that makes the OS consider it to be foreground and therefore eligible for starting services. I haven't had a chance to test the theory yet, though I hope to in the next few days.

Comment: "For instance, for background execution you have to use JobScheduler" From an ArsTechnica article talking to some Googlers, but yeah doesn't specifically mention starting services. [Article](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/05/ars-talks-android-googlers-chat-about-project-treble-os-updates-and-linux/)

Comment: @CommonsWare: you piqued my interest so I had a look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/JobServiceContext.java). First of all, there's this: `EXECUTING_TIMESLICE_MILLIS = 10 * 60 * 1000`, so it does timeout after 10 minutes. Second of all, The OS' `JobServiceContext`does bind to the `JobService`, which should probably raise it to foreground, but it binds it with the `BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND` flag. So the service shouldn't raise the app to foreground, but we're still able to start a background service?

Comment: @OriWasserman: FWIW, that link is to the `master` branch, which may or may not reflect changes made in O.

Comment: @CommonsWare: You're right, my bad, but it still uses the `BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND` flag on the [android-o-preview-2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-o-preview-2/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/JobServiceContext.java) tag